# Stop Credentials Choose Dialog Android

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I am trying to use google smartlock on my android app. I saved two credentials to the smartlock (passwords.google.com) and on my app, I get a dialog asking me to choose one of the two credentials. The problem is even after I set "Offer To Save Password" and "Auto Sign-In" to off, I keep getting the dialog to choose credentials. I need a way to disable the dialog. Is there some other setting that I need to do else where?

Comment: Are you the developer of the app? Can you control when you resolve the Android Intent that renders the UI? Otherwise, from user-side, delete any extraneous credentials from the password manager settings / passwords.google.com ?

Comment: @StevenSoneff yes, I am the developer. I believe I can do all that you mentioned. But my understanding of smartlock is, if I turn off the above-mentioned settings from passwords.google.com, my android device (signed in with my gmail) shouldn't prompt me for the credential resolutions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to disable the dialog? Is it for testing? When we designed the feature, the thinking is that user may want to control being prompted to save new info, but if they already have info saved, then give them access to it when they might need it (otherwise, they can just delete the saved credentials altogether)

Comment: I want to provide a way to the user to control whether they want the help of smartlock during login/sign up. I was hoping that by turning the above-mentioned settings off, the app will stop showing the credential resolution dialog. If that's not the case then I need to find an alternate strategy

Comment: As above, can't you control when the Android Intent is fired to show the picker? So you could gate this on some indication from the user that they want the help?

Comment: I can control that. So is it correct to conclude that your "Offer To Save Password" and "Auto Sign-In" settings on passwords.google.com doesn't hide/show the credential resolution dialog on you android app? If the call is made to the credentials api and if there is need for resolution, the dialog will show no matter what you settings are on passwords.google.com

Comment: That's the current behavior, yes. Save password and Auto sign-in settings intended to only control those features per se

Answer (score 0):

I'm the PM for the team that designed and build this functionality.

There's no way to disable the dialog from settings ("Offer To Save Password" and "Auto Sign-In" settings only control those features, per se). The rationale for this was that if a user has credentials stored, then Smart Lock will offer them when the user might need them (otherwise user probably best off to delete the credentials if they are not useful).

As a developer, though, you can choose when to resolve the credential picker Intent, and thus control when the UI appears in your app.